# replacing the items of a nested list based on indices?

Tags: python

The question is simply "How to replace the predicted values by each ML models with the actual values in order to compare and visualize the predictions?".

I have searched most of the questions regarding the replacements of the elements of a nested list based on indices. I tried to use a function to change each sub-list of the nested list based on the indices with a replacement lists.

```
def replace_elements(original_list, replacement_list, indices):
    for i in range(len(indices)):
        index = indices[i]
        if index < len(original_list):
            original_list[index] = replacement_list[i]
        else:
            raise IndexError("Index out of range")
    return original_list
```

then I tried to replace the predicted values by different ML models with the actual values like below:

```
indices_to_change = [1, 53, 90, 28, 57, 44, 2, 109, 4, 47, 8, 5, 15, 24, 14, 89, 80, 86, 33, 106, 95, 111, 29, 42]

nested_list = [Nearest_Neighbors, Gradient_Boosting, Decision_Tree,XGBosst,Random_Forest,Neural_Net]
new_ls = []
for i in range (6):
    original_list = nested_list[i]
    replacement_list = predicted[i]
    indices = indices_to_change
    res = replace_elements(original_list,replacement_list,indices)
    new_ls.append(res)
```

This code works if I have only one list But when there is a nested list the result that I obtain is not correct. It repeats the whole replacements for the whole list similarly. It does not incorporates the other results.

Imagine the nested list is like this `[[1,2,4,5],[2,3,5,1],[8,1,4,2]]` then I want to change the indices of `[2,1]` of each sub-list respectively by `[[1,1],[2,1],[3,1]]` so the new list becomes `[[1,1,4,5],[1,2,5,1],[1,3,4,2]]`.

All helps will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide us with more details? like some of the results you obtained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a good question. You simply should change the function which you have written like this:

```
def replace_list_items(original_list, replacement_list, indices):
new_list = original_list.copy()
for i, index in enumerate(indices):
    if index < len(original_list):
        new_list[index] = replacement_list[i]
    else:
        raise IndexError("Index out of range")
return new_list
```

then use this way:

```
nested_list = [Nearest_Neighbors, Gradient_Boosting,Decision_Tree,XGBosst,Random_Forest,Neural_Net]
results = []
for i in range (6):
    original_list = nested_list[i]
    replacement_list = predicted[i]
    indices = indices_to_change
    new_list = replace_list_items(original_list, replacement_list, indices)
    results.append(new_list)
    
print(results)
```

then it works. I hope it works for you as well